# $f:[-1,1]\to \mathbb{R}$ concave then maximum is at most $2f(0)$

Tags: real-analysis, inequality

Let $f:[-1,1] \to \mathbb{R}^+$ a concave function with maximum in $x_0 \in (0,1)$.

How can I prove that $f(x_0) \le 2 f(0)$?

Comment: Result looks false to me. Take $f(x)=x-x^{10}$. Maximum is at $x_0=0.7743$ with value $0.6968$, value at 0 is 0.

Comment: Is it $\mathbb R$ or $\mathbb R^+?$ Please share your thoughts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$f$ has to be increasing on $[-1,x_0]$ and decreasing in $[x_0,1]$. Since 
$$
0=-1\left(1-\frac{1}{1+x_0}\right)+x_0\cdot \frac{1}{1+x_0}
$$
then by Jensen inequality
$$
f(0) \ge \left(1-\frac{1}{1+x_0}\right)f(-1)+\frac{1}{1+x_0}f(x_0).
$$
Since $f(-1) \ge 0$, it follows that
$$
2f(0) \ge \frac{2}{1+x_0}f(x_0) \ge f(x_0).
$$

Answer (score 0):

Notice that we can write $0 = \frac 12 x_0 + \frac 12 (-x_0)$. Then applying the definition of concavity we obtain $$f(0) \ge \frac 12f(x_0) + \frac 12 f(-x_0) \ge \frac 12f(x_0),$$ where in the last inequality we've used the fact that $f$ takes only positive values.